# Multiple if statements to categorize a random number in a partitioned interval

Tags: python-3.x, random

I am partitioning a random number to be in one of 2 cases to simulate a roll of a die. The problem is that sometimes, there is more than one step per loop. Please see the MWE below:

```
    count = 0
    n = random.random()

    while count = 1/2:
            n = random.random() # generate a new random number
            print("   Tails")

        count = count + 1
```

Output

```
    Count = 0
       Heads
       Tails
    Count = 1
       Heads
    Count = 2
       Heads
       Tails
    Count = 3
       Heads
       Tails
    Count = 4
       Heads
    Count = 5
       Heads
    Count = 6
       Heads
       Tails
    Count = 7
       Tails
    Count = 8
       Tails
    Count = 9
       Tails
    Count = 10
       Tails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you exactly want, but I wish it help you.

```
import random

for i in range(N): # N : how many repeats.
    n = random.random()
    print("Count =", i)
    if n > 0.5 :   # 50%
        print("    Heads")
    else :         # other 50%
        print("    Tails")
```

Answer (score 0):

What part of MWE is responsible for `Heads` apperaring on the output?